# Why aren't FontAwesome icons displaying?

Tags: font-awesome

I started coding my website in one folder and everything works fine. The icons display without a problem. Then I needed to move the code to a different folder and I copy-pasted the *exact* same files with the exact same code. The icons no longer display in the folder I need. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Could You provide your folder and file structure and your code (html & css)?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be tested by others.